How to instantly update URL param using router.push() and router.refresh() and display loader while fetching data in Next.js?
Here is my code below
page.jsx
import { getAllWorkflows } from "@/actions/workflow";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default async function Page({ searchParams }) {
  const Workflow = dynamic(() => import("./_components/Workflow"), {
    ssr: false,
  });
  const filterObject = {
    search: searchParams?.search || "",
    current_page: Number(searchParams?.page) || 1,
  };
  const response = await getAllWorkflows(filterObject);
 

  return <Workflow workflowResponse={response?.data} filterObject={filterObject} />
}

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Workflows',
  description: '',
}

Workflow.jsx
"use client"

import WorkflowTable from "../../_components/_workflow/WorkflowTable";
import DashboardWrapper from "../../_components/DashboardWrapper";
import { workflowColumns } from "../../_components/_workflow/workflowColumns";
import { formatWorkflowTableData } from "@/lib/utils";

export default function Workflow({ workflowResponse, filterObject, toolbarConfig, classes, folderSelectedID }) {
  return (
    <DashboardWrapper className={classes ? classes : ""}>
      <div className="flex h-full flex-1 flex-col space-y-6">
        <WorkflowTable
          data={formatWorkflowTableData(workflowResponse?.data)}
          columns={workflowColumns(toolbarConfig)}
          toolbarConfig={toolbarConfig}
          pagination={{
            pageIndex: workflowResponse?.current_page - 1,
            pageSize: workflowResponse?.total_pages,
            totalData: workflowResponse?.total,
          }}
          filterObject={filterObject}
          folderSelectedID={folderSelectedID}
        />
      </div>
    </DashboardWrapper>
  );
}

WorkflowTable.jsx
const handleUrlForPage = (index) => {
  const pageNo = index + 1;
  setTableLoading(true);
  if (pageNo) {
    params.set('page', pageNo);
  } else {
    params.delete('page');
  }
  push(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
}

When I click on a page number, there is a 3-second delay before the URL gets updated, and then Workflow.jsx is updated with the new data based on the selected page. How can I speed up this process to instantly update the URL when a page is clicked? If that’s not possible, how can I display a loader while the URL is being updated, and stop the loader once the new data has been fetched?
I tried many custom solution and did many research on that but did not find any accurate solution.

You can use Suspense and a key  to show a loading spinner when data is being fetched. This is how I have done it, and you can use the same approach .
DashboardPropertiesMain
import React from 'react';

import Header from '@/components/pages/DashboardPropertiesPage/Header';
import TableWrapper from '@/components/pages/DashboardPropertiesPage/TableWrapper';
import Skeleton from '@/components/ui/DashboardPropertiesTable/Skeleton';
import { PropertiesStatusFilterEnum } from '@/enums';
import { UserType } from '@/types';

type Props = {
  currentPage: number;
  userData: UserType | undefined;
  status?: PropertiesStatusFilterEnum;
};
export default function DashboardPropertiesMain({
  currentPage,
  userData,
  status,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <section className=" max-w-[1300px] xl:px-6 lg:px-3 sm:px-6 px-4 mx-auto ">
      <br />
      <br className="xl:block hidden" />
      <Header />
      <React.Suspense key={`${currentPage}-${status}`} fallback={<Skeleton />}>
        <TableWrapper
          status={status}
          userData={userData}
          currentPage={currentPage}
        />
      </React.Suspense>
      <br className="xl:block hidden" />
      <br />
    </section>
  );
}

Wrapper component:
import React from 'react';

import { DashboardPropertiesTable } from '@/components/ui/DashboardPropertiesTable';
import { PropertiesStatusFilterEnum, Roles } from '@/enums';
import { getAllProperties, getMyProperties } from '@/server/data-lib';
type Props = {
  currentPage: number;
  status?: PropertiesStatusFilterEnum;
};
export default async function TableWrapper({
  currentPage,
  status,
}: Props) {
  let  propertiesData = await getMyProperties(currentPage, status);


  return (
    <DashboardPropertiesTable
      data={propertiesData.data}
      totalDocs={propertiesData.totalDocs}
      currentPage={currentPage}
    />
  );
}

Page component:
import DashboardPropertiesMain from '@/components/pages/DashboardPropertiesPage';
import { PropertiesStatusFilterEnum, Roles } from '@/enums';
import { getMe } from '@/server/data-lib';
import { redirectBaseOnRole } from '@/server/helper';
import { UserType } from '@/types';

export default async function DashboardHome({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams?: {
    page?: string;
    status?: PropertiesStatusFilterEnum;
  };
}) {
  const currentPage = Number(searchParams?.page) || 1;
  return (
    <DashboardPropertiesMain
      currentPage={currentPage}
      status={searchParams?.status}
    />
  );
}

